How to Instantiate a Class with dependency on IIndex in Autofac with C# .NET Framework
I am using autofac with Keyed type registration in C# .NET 4.7 to choose concrete classes at runtime.  The following approach works, but I'm not convinced it's the best.
I have a class like this:
public class ReportProcessor
{
    private readonly IIndex<Models.Enums.ReportType, IReportGenerator> _generatorDict;

    public ReportProcessor(IIndex<Models.Enums.ReportType, IReportGenerator> generatorDict)
    {
        _generatorDict = generatorDict;
    }

    public bool Process(ReportJob job)
    {
        bool success = false;

        var generator = _generatorDict[job.Type];

        generator.GenerateReport();

        return success;
    }
}

And in the Main block, I want to do something like this:
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("The Report Generator is starting.");

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<ReportProcessor>().As<IReportProcessor>();
        builder.RegisterType<FunReportGenerator>().Keyed<IReportGenerator>(ReportType.Fun);
        builder.RegisterType<BoringReportGenerator>().Keyed<IReportGenerator>(ReportType.Boring);
        var container = builder.Build();

        IReportProcessor rp = container.Resolve<IReportProcessor>();
        List<ReportJob> pendingJobs = new List<ReportJob>();
        List<Task<bool>> tasks = new List<Task<bool>>();

        foreach(ReportJob job in pendingJobs)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => rp.Process(job)));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The Report Generator has finished.");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}

But clearly I'm missing something because I can instantiate the ReportProcessor class directly as written.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Please show us how you are trying to instantiate the class with the autufac and what error you get. At the first glance, it appears that you have not  registered the ReportProcessor class in the container at all, so it cannot be resolved because of it.

The error was coming up that I wasn't feeding in the IIndex parameter to the constructor.  I added builder.RegisterType<ReportProcessor>().As<IReportProcessor>(); and then used IReportProcessor rp = container.Resolve<IReportProcessor>(); to instantiate the processor.  It is working this way, but I'm still not sure if this is best.  I edited my initial question to reflect this change.

You have dependency on IIndex, so you need to register it with DI container as well.

"Is it the best?" is a opinion-based, so it is unlikely that you will get the answer. But the current implementation is absolutely ok for the autofac and will work as expected.
